# De-installing windows?

Tags: system

I'm **totally** new to the linux world, so I know it might not be a wise decision to completely de-install windows 10 (which I have in dual boot with Juno).

Still, despite of the nerving sound problem, which seems to happen only to me, since nobody answered my question about it, I'm feeling inclined to get rid of windows for good and keep elementary as the only OS.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an EFI install you can simply use a program like GParted or Gnome Disk Utility to delete the Windows partitions (not including the EFI partition) and then run 'sudo update-grub'. If you run 'sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu' what do you see?

Comment: First, I have no idea what EFI is. I'm an absolute beginner at this. And then I would like to erase everything completely from the computer, eOS included, and start fresh anew, like, tabula rasa. Maybe some strange things going on with this computer would get fixed.

Comment: That's much simpler. Just boot the live USB and when get to the partitioning portion select the option that says "Erase disk and install elementary" (or similar.) That will remove/delete absolutely everything.

Comment: If you want to be more certain it's all gone open 'Gparted' from the main menu at the top (of the live USB) and go 'Device > Create Partition Table > Apply'.

Comment: Thanks. A lot! :)